# How to parse Javascript array to c# List/Dictionary

Tags: c#, javascript, list, dictionary

I have 2 separate system, My first system will return a java script like bellow

```
var st=[];
var at=[];
var bt=[];
var ht=[];
ht[0]=['015',5,'33087443','23','50','22','x'];
ht[1]=['018',5,'45648783','53','10','20','z'];
```

My second system will grab all this java script to process it and store into database , is that any parser or any way to allow me to separate all this different `var st , at, bt, ht` into a list or dictionary ?

my expected outcome is list/dictionary : - (so that it easily for me to access the data)

```
List/Dictionary st = //All that array value
List/Dictionary at = //All that array value
List/Dictionary ht = //All that array value
```

Comment: You better use some well-known format as an intermediate protocol between your programs. Like JSON or XML

Comment: Looks like you need a Javascript interpreter with .NET bindings, that supports inspecting JS objects from C# code.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, I would recommend altering your system to return JSON data, not javascript as it is more easily consumed by .Net. Using Javascript will require that you either use the outdated MSScript control or JInt. Speaking from experience, neither of which are very pleasant to work with.